# Access a test network from other network

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, switch, remote-access

I have four test computers connected together in a small test network (as shown below). Two of the computers are in ESXi and two physical computers. They are all configured with the same IP address used by the customer.

The problem is that I want to access the computers from my work computer on the office network (which is on a completely different IP range). I want to access them via Remote Desktop and I want to also be able to access the office server from the test computers.
Is this possible with simple and inexpensive means?
I have no permission to change in the office network.

```
=====================
||ESXi              ||
||     A       B    ||
||     |       |    ||
||     ---------    || (virtual switch)
||         |        ||
||=========|=========
           |
    -----------------  (switch)
    |               |
=======         =======
||C  ||         ||D  ||
||   ||         ||   ||
=======         =======
```

**Edit**

It is possible to add an extra virtual machine to the virtual network in ESXi with dual NICs. One for the  test network, and one for the office network.
I can also replace the physical switch I use for the testing network if it would help.

Comment: Is the switch a managed switch with vlan support?

Comment: The switch is a simple standard switch. But if it helps, I can replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need routing between the two networks. If you can't reach one from the other in *some* way, then you're out of luck. You'll either need to have a network admin set up routes between them, or configure a VPN between them assuming there's minimal connectivity (i.e. over the public Internet).

If you can have a multi-homed VM, just make that VM into a router and set it as the gateway for anything that needs to get off of the test network. As for things getting *to* the test network, you'll still need a network admin to add a route to it on their end.

Comment: I answered your question in a edit of the question
I'm not that experienced. How can VPN to help me?

Comment: Updated with details.